# Most appropriate way to develop a server on limited resources

Tags: php, c++, timeout, webserver

I am facing a problem which seems to have few, and especially simple solutions.
To get to the point; I have written a client application on Windows using C++.
This client application takes input from the user, and is supposed to send this
information to a server, which find users who's inputs match each other - like matchmaking.

How can I (an indie developer) with most ease solve this problem, IF and only if I
cannot host the server application myself, and do not want to spend money on renting
a whole virtual private server?

Most preferred, I want to write this server using sockets in PHP and just rent a
web-server with unlimited bandwidth, but it seems to have far too many restrictions,
related to timeouts (PHP's set_time_limit, Apache's timeout value and the internal OS
timeout value).

**So to sum up the question, and in a generic form**; How can I as an indie developer create
a server application which do not require using my own bandwidth and without expensive purchases for items such as a virtual private server.

Comment: So you want to have an undefined amount of resources available by not using your bandwith or paying for an actual server hooked to a 100mbit wire? You got 2 options - create something like what Skype uses (supernodes of idle users and use their bandwith / processing power) or give up :) it's not like you can do something without either clever engineering or money.

Comment: VPS are not that expensive compared to a web hosting I believe?

Comment: It is true that VPS aren't that expensive but it seems as such an overkill. Since I only want to use a single server program which might not even need more than 16 MB RAM. Therefore a webserver seems more appropriate, but as previously mentioned, it seems to have far too many limitations. I guess VPS might be the only option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just code your server application in PHP as a **webservice**.

In your client application, instead of connecting through sockets and a using a home-made protocol, you just have to use the HTTP REST webservice you created. It seems to me even easier than coding a whole server.

Maybe you absolutely want to use socket on your server, but you didn't specify that in your question.

Comment: This was interesting indeed. Although I do not believe that this
has the horsepower necessary for my needs. Stupid enough, I didn't
mention that all this "matchmaking" takes place in real-time - up to 100 connections
per minute.

Comment: I see, but this may be worth looking into it still. A webservice response time can be around 10ms if there's not too much processing involved (and given you need a very "basic" webserver, I suppose it's feasible). I don't guarantee that it will do though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a cloud hosting provider, such as [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/).